# Native query changed by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently trying to execute this method in my repository:

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT a.ID as 'ID', a.STATUS as 'STATUS', a.SOURCE as 'SOURCE', a.EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_ID as 'EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_ID', s.ID as 'STREET_ID', l.ID as 'LOCALITY_ID', c.ID as 'COUNTRY_ID', p.ID as 'POSTCODE_ID', a.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as 'INSERTED_TIMESTAMP', a.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP as 'UPDATED_TIMESTAMP', a.DELETED_TIMESTAMP as 'DELETED_TIMESTAMP'\n" +
        "FROM address_management_svc.subaddress sa\n" +
        "INNER JOIN address_management_svc.address a\n" +
        "ON (sa.ADDRESS_ID = a.ID)\n" +
        "INNER JOIN street s\n" +
        "ON (s.id = a.STREET_ID)\n" +
        "INNER JOIN locality l\n" +
        "ON (l.id = a.LOCALITY_ID)\n" +
        "INNER JOIN country c\n" +
        "ON (c.id = a.COUNTRY_ID)\n" +
        "INNER JOIN post_code p\n" +
        "ON (p.id = a.POSTCODE_ID)", nativeQuery = true)
List<AddressEntity> getAll();
```

I switched on the jpa logging and for some reason, I am getting all of this (below is a sample as in reality I am getting all records like this which is hundreds of thousands)

```
    select
        streetenti0_.ID as id1_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.DELETED_TIMESTAMP as deleted_2_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_ID as external3_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as inserted4_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.LOCALITY_ID as locality9_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.NAME as name5_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.SOURCE as source6_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.STATUS as status7_4_0_,
        streetenti0_.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP as updated_8_4_0_,
        localityen1_.ID as id1_2_1_,
        localityen1_.COUNTRY_ID as country_9_2_1_,
        localityen1_.DELETED_TIMESTAMP as deleted_2_2_1_,
        localityen1_.EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_ID as external3_2_1_,
        localityen1_.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as inserted4_2_1_,
        localityen1_.NAME as name5_2_1_,
        localityen1_.SOURCE as source6_2_1_,
        localityen1_.STATUS as status7_2_1_,
        localityen1_.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP as updated_8_2_1_,
        countryent2_.ID as id1_1_2_,
        countryent2_.DELETED_TIMESTAMP as deleted_2_1_2_,
        countryent2_.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as inserted3_1_2_,
        countryent2_.NAME as name4_1_2_,
        countryent2_.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP as updated_5_1_2_ 
    from
        STREET streetenti0_ 
    left outer join
        LOCALITY localityen1_ 
            on streetenti0_.LOCALITY_ID=localityen1_.ID 
    left outer join
        COUNTRY countryent2_ 
            on localityen1_.COUNTRY_ID=countryent2_.ID 
    where
        streetenti0_.ID=?
2021-09-06 17:06:19.012 address-management-service TRACE natty-lappy-work [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [179779]
2021-09-06 17:06:19.031 address-management-service DEBUG natty-lappy-work [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - 
    select
        localityen0_.ID as id1_2_0_,
        localityen0_.COUNTRY_ID as country_9_2_0_,
        localityen0_.DELETED_TIMESTAMP as deleted_2_2_0_,
        localityen0_.EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_ID as external3_2_0_,
        localityen0_.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as inserted4_2_0_,
        localityen0_.NAME as name5_2_0_,
        localityen0_.SOURCE as source6_2_0_,
        localityen0_.STATUS as status7_2_0_,
        localityen0_.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP as updated_8_2_0_,
        countryent1_.ID as id1_1_1_,
        countryent1_.DELETED_TIMESTAMP as deleted_2_1_1_,
        countryent1_.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as inserted3_1_1_,
        countryent1_.NAME as name4_1_1_,
        countryent1_.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP as updated_5_1_1_ 
    from
        LOCALITY localityen0_ 
    left outer join
        COUNTRY countryent1_ 
            on localityen0_.COUNTRY_ID=countryent1_.ID 
    where
        localityen0_.ID=?
```

I want it to execute the exact statement I give it, without translating anything. I also had it set to `nativeQuery = true` but that doesn't seem to help. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Are you really sure that you are calling getAll and not findAll?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yeah. FindAll takes over 2 hours actually, and I debugged the code and it goes in this statement

Comment: The point is that you are returning entities. That way HIbernate has to fetch the data needed to construct the entities. Do you really need entites?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes I will need the entities to then do conversion to DTOs and return those. Is there another way to achieve this with less performance impact?

Comment: Or there are many. You could use JPA constructor expression or jOOQ multiset. What database are you using? Are you using Spring/Spring Boot?

Comment: MySQL Postgress database and yes I am using Spring Boot

Comment: Do you need nested objects or flat DTOs? If you need nested read this: https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(AddressEntity.class)
public interface AddressDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getStatus();
    String getSource();
    String getExternalReferenceId();
    @Mapping("street.id")
    Long getStreetId();
    @Mapping("locality.id")
    Long getLocalityId();
    @Mapping("country.id")
    Long getCountryId();
    @Mapping("postCode.id")
    Long getPostcodeId();
    Instant getInsertedTimestamp();
    Instant getUpdatedTimestamp();
    Instant getDeletedTimestamp();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`AddressDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, AddressDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<AddressDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

In your case, it will even avoid all the joins and just select the foreign keys as they are in the `address` table.